# C: long pointer pointing to address with an integer

Tags: c, pointers, printf

Why does the first printf() output 1 and the second one 8589934593?
EDIT: Why does the second one output exactly 8589934593 and not some other number?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int *intPtr = NULL;
    long *longPtr = NULL;

    int array[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
    intPtr = &array[1];
    longPtr = &array[1];
    printf("%d\n", *intPtr);
    printf("%ld\n", *longPtr);
}
```

Comment: Enable compiler warnings: https://ideone.com/9m8gW1

Comment: turbo C? have you checked `sizeof(int)` vs `sizeof(long)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Comment: Learn  what **undefined behaviour** is. You definitively will meet it many times in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's undefined behavior. Pointing a `long*` to the address of an `int` and acting like it's a `long` violates the strict aliasing rule, giving you undefined behavior.

Comment: But why does it output 8589934593 and not some other number?

Comment: @AndrejCoding Because it's undefined, it can print anything or blow up your computer.

Comment: So for some compilers, it could output e.g. 123 or whatever?
It just outputs 8589934593 for my particular compiler because the compiler defined it somewhere?

Comment: @AndrejCoding it's because that's just what happens to be in memory at that address on your computer at the time you run it. If you run it again later you may get a different result, or if you change something that causes the compiler to use a different address, etc.

Comment: print in hex `>>> hex(8589934593 )
'0x200000001'`. Now you're sure the compiler read the data with a shift or something.

Comment: @AndrejCoding Because it happened to be in memory.

Comment: Thanks, guys! I will mark this answer as correct in 8min!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Fancy seeing you here